# Walkable sprite help

Tags: android, animation, image-manipulation, sprite

I’m trying to make a sprite that is stationary at the start but once
you click somewhere on the screen, it should move to that point
automatically in a straight line, creating the walking effect.
How do I do this?

Comment: i'm done with the animation of the walking part i.e when the app 
is launched, my sprite looks like this:
http://obviam.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/walk_elaine_anim.gif 
I can now control the animation also i.e. only make it walk on 
generation of a certain event.
I just need help in making it move from one point to another along a 
straight line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, your question is a little vague, and therefore hard to answer.  Generally speaking, you can make a translate animation as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html
Or, you can just do the drawing yourself: record the location of the touch event, interpolate some positions between that location and your sprite's starting position, and draw some frames yourself.